# database or sessions ? where to store tokens

Tags: php, token

tokens are great tool to prevent **csrf** attack

for every request made by user , your system must generate a unique token and store it somewhere

the next time the client ask to perform some actions , the system verify if the token exist , and if it still valid

if we store tokens in sessions , then sessions will become too large , an this will cost a lot of memory as the CPU load the entire sessions in ram when responding to a request , and with a CPU of 1Gb for example , and 1000 users with 1 sessions of 1Mb each , the CPU will not handle anything , this could be a typical ddos attack ( to request more and more tokens knowing they are stored in sessions)

in the other side storing tokens in database have his own weakness ,

which method do you use to store tokens ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sessions, 1MB per session is pretty high IMO. Since PHP's Session handler can be switched to use a different back end, you have the flexibility of storing them on disk / memcached / mysql down the road.

Comment: what is the maximum number of tokens that you allow for one user

Comment: One per session, see https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#General_Recommendation:_Synchronizer_Token_Pattern

Comment: Sure, though you should expire them or regenerate them periodically. Just make sure to test that an invalid token doesn't cause user's to lose form state.